# Why does every complete theory have a model?

Tags: first-order-logic

I have to prove that $T$ is complete iff $T=Th(\frak{A})$ for a $\tau$-structure $\mathfrak{A}$.

If $Th(\mathfrak{A})=T$ and $\psi$ is a $FO(\tau)$ proposition (I don't know the english expression but I want to say that $\psi$ has no free variables). Then either $\mathfrak{A}\models\psi$ or $A\not\models\psi$. Thus $T$ is complete.

Now for the other direction assuming $T$ is complete, if I would know that there is a structure $\mathfrak{A}$ such that $\mathfrak{A}\models T$. Then I could say $ T\subseteq Th{\mathfrak{(A)}}$. Then looking at $\psi\in FO(\tau)$ in the case of $\mathfrak{A}\models \psi$, then because of completeness we have also either $T\models \psi$ or $T\not\models \psi$ , the second option is not possible. Because of the subsetrelation if $\mathfrak{A}\not\models \psi$ then also $T\not\models \psi$.

The question is how can I prove the existence of a model for $T$?

Comment: The English word for $\psi$ having no free variables is *sentence*.

Answer (score 3):

This is highly nontrivial - it's the [Completeness Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem) **CT** ("completeness" in its name refers to the *proof system*'s completeness, not the completeness of any particular first-order theory.). I've given a quick summary of its proof in the first part of [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2099585/28111).

Specifically, **CT** says that every consistent theory has a model. A theory $T$ is complete iff *$T$ is consistent and* for each $\varphi$ exactly one of $\varphi$ and $\neg\varphi$ is in $T$. Since complete theories are consistent, **CT** says that complete theories in particular have models.

(OK, that may not be the definition of "complete theory" you're using; the other common one is that $T$ is complete iff $T$ is consistent and for each $\varphi$ exactly one of $\varphi$ or $\neg\varphi$ is in $T$. But that doesn't change the argument above.)

---

In case you're already familiar with the completeness theorem for *propositional* logic, it's worth noting that despite their similarities they are really fundamentally different - the propositional version is comparatively trivial. Similarly, the compactness theorem for propositional logic has a quick topological proof, whose idea [breaks down](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3316199/28111) for the first-order case.

Basically, the difference is that in propositional logic the semantics is already very close to the syntax: a "model" in the sense of propositional logic is simply an assignment of truth values to the sentences which satisfies some basic rules (e.g. it makes $A\wedge B$ true iff it makes $A$ true and it makes $B$ true). By contrast, the semantics for first-order logic is extremely complicated: **a structure is much more than just its theory** (whereas in the propositional case, a structure literally *is* its theory).

*One technical way to make this precise is to observe that we can whip up a single first-order sentence with no **computable** model (e.g. take $I\Sigma_1+\neg Con(I\Sigma_1)$ and apply Tennenbaum's theorem).*

Comment: Let me reframe my question if $T$ is complete how can I prove that there exists a $\mathfrak{A}$ such that $T=Th(\mathfrak{A})$ ?

Comment: @New2Math That's what I've answered. In your post you gave a correct argument showing that if $T$ is complete and has a model then $T$ is the theory of that model. So all you're missing is to prove that a complete theory has some model, and that's what I've done here.